# Formmail Redirect Issue

Tags: php, html, scripting, formmail

I'm trying to get a Formmail form to re-direct back to it's own page.  For example, if I'm on the page, http://www.rightfittech.com/paincenter/contact-us.html, I would like the re-direct to go back to http://www.rightfittech.com/paincenter/contact-us.html, which is the same page.

I searched Google like crazy, and no worthwhile results.  The forums keep saying to create a hidden input field

BUT THIS IS NOT WORKING!!!

My code below, and note that I didn't modify formmail, except for email addresses!

```
<form action="http://www.rightfittech.com/paincenter/formmail.php" name="Contact" method="post"
id="form1">
             <input type="hidden" name="env_report" value="REMOTE_HOST,REMOTE_ADDR,HTTP_USER_AGENT,AUTH_TYPE,REMOTE_USER" >
             <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="http://www.rightfittech.com/paincenter/contact-us.html"/>
             <input type="hidden" name="recipients" value="robertmyrick@hotmail.com" >
             <input type="hidden" name="mail_options" value="FromAddr=robertmyrick@hotmail.com" > 
             <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="New Contact" >
          <div class="wrapper row-2">
            <div class="col-1">
              <div class="form">
                <label>First Name:</label>
                <input type="text" />
              </div>
              <div class="form">
                <label>Last Name:</label>
                <input type="text" />
              </div>
              <div class="form">
                <label>E-mail:</label><br/>
                <input type="text" />
              </div>
              <div class="form">
                <label>Phone Number:</label>
                <input type="text" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
              <div>
                <label>Enter Your Message:</label>
                <textarea cols="1" rows="1"></textarea>
              </div>

              <div class="wrapper">
              <div class="alignright" style="float:left">
              <a href="#" class="link2" onclick="document.getElementById('form1').reset()"><em><b>Clear</b></em></a>

              <div style="width:20px; float:left">&nbsp;</div>

              <a href="#" class="link2" onclick="document.getElementById('form1').submit()"><em><b>Submit</b></em></a></div>
                                                            </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: You forgot to include your `formmail` script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the value `good_url` instead of `redirect`.

Like so:

```
<input type="hidden" name="good_url"
       value="http://www.rightfittech.com/paincenter/contact-us.html"/>
```